Error configuring services in an external startup class. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsof t.Extensions.Options, Version=8.0.0.0
I have a funciton app running on .NET8.0 and few other class libraries running on .NET8.0 as well. I need to make use of Microsoft.Extensions.Options Library on my project and I've installed the 8.0.0 version of it.
The Project builds fine but I'm having the following runtime error, even though the package is installed.
Error configuring services in an external startup class. Error configuring services in an external startup class. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Found some people reporting ⁠similar issues and downgrading the package for the solution to run, doing that resolved this error but it caused some other errors throughout the solution due to the incompatibilities of .NET and the Package itself.
Tried clearing/restoring packages but still had the issue persisted.
Any Idea what could be causing this issue/ how to resolve this?
Thank you!

Could you share the code please? Maybe the startup code and the .csproj

You need to have given packages in .csproj file If you are using .NET8 in-process function.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>_78902217</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I am able to get expected response.

If you are using .NET8 isolated function then you should have given packages in .csproj file.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="8.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class HttpFunction
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HttpFunction> _logger;

        public HttpFunction(ILogger<HttpFunction> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("HttpFunction")]
        public static HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] 
        HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            var logger = executionContext.GetLogger(nameof(HttpFunction));
            logger.LogInformation("message logged");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            response.WriteString("Welcome to .NET isolated worker !!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}

It worked as expected.

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5907 Commit hash: N/A +807e89766a92b14fd07b9f0bc2bea1d8777ab209 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-08-26T07:43:52.029Z] Found C:\Users\*****\repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-08-26T07:43:54.487Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 28572) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-08-26T07:43:54.529Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        HttpFunction: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7103/api/HttpFunction

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-08-26T07:43:59.623Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000000D2022A4'.
[2024-08-26T07:44:10.554Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpFunction' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=b19bfd27-0a72-4f90-b76e-5d7ab923219e)
[2024-08-26T07:44:10.683Z] message logged
[2024-08-26T07:44:10.811Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpFunction' (Succeeded, Id=b19bfd27-0a72-4f90-b76e-5d7ab923219e, Duration=295ms)

